# What is the best practice to save a module state on Magento 2.3.x?

Tags: magento2.3.3, magento2.3.x

I need to save/retrieve information gathered my module. The information might be anything big or small. There may be one or many variables to save and retrieve.

I have identified three ways to save a module state in Magento :

1. Using Config (core_config_data).
2. Using Variable (variables) also known as "Custom variables".
3. Using own resources using a new table in the database.

Which one should I use to save a module state?
Are there known best practice for this scenario?

Comment: you mean the module status? Like enabled/disabled?

Comment: I need to save/retrieve information gathered by the module. The information might be anything big or small. There may be one or many variables to save and retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store data temporarily between script executions or sessions, you might want to look at [FlagManager](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/FlagManager.php). Data is stored in the `flag` table.

Usages in core: https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?q=flagManager-%3EsaveFlag&unscoped_q=flagManager-%3EsaveFlag